# How to change click event of button according to different situations on Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

I use Angular 9 to develop a web application. So I need to use Bootstrap Modals
like as

```
 <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">{{MODAL_TITLE}}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{MODAL_BODY}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" (click)="function_1()" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I called a function when I clicked the Submit button. Well, I just want to change the function that submit function called in different cases.

So the thing that I just want to do in ts file:

```
MODAL_BODY = "BODY STRING";

MODAL_TITLE: FUNCTION ;
modal.show();

function1(){
console.log("function 1 works"}
}

function2(){
console.log("function 2 works")
}
```

I want to use function2() instead of function1() sometimes.

Then I want to change function that submit button called in different situations just like as:

```
    <button type="button" (click)="function_1()" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>

//some times i need to use this button below. so I need to change it from ts file

    <button type="button" (click)="function_2()" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
```

Is there anyway to do that? from ts file or dynamically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An alternative idea is, where you have one button in the template that has one handler function with one parameter. And based on this parameter an `if` or `switch` decides, which modal is displayed.

Comment: @MilanTenk yeap. i've just thinked it. But I wonder that is it possible the way that I wrote?

Comment: You can use angulars `*ngIf` directive, to achieve exactly what @MilanTemk suggested, but in the template

Answer (score 1):

If we want to change dynamically the button itself in the template the `*ngIf` structural directive can be used. (As chrnx writes in the question comment.)
To have an example for this take a look at the example below.

In Angular template code:

```
<p>
  Used button
  <br />
  <button *ngIf="displayedButton === 1" (click)="onButtonOneClick()">
    ButtonOne
  </button>
  <button *ngIf="displayedButton === 2" (click)="onButtonTwoClick()">
    ButtonTwo
  </button>
</p>
<p>
  Change button state
  <br />
  <button (click)="onChangeStateClick()">Change</button>
</p>
```

In component code:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  displayedButton = 1;

  onButtonOneClick() {
    console.log("Button 1 click");
  }

  onButtonTwoClick() {
    console.log("Button 2 click");
  }

  onChangeStateClick() {
    this.displayedButton = this.displayedButton === 1 ? 2 : 1;
  }
}
```

Stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-irmbkk?file=src/app/app.component.ts